# Display/Shown event for User Control

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls, devexpress

I want to popup/show a dialog when ever my user control is displayed/shown. But I couldn't find any such event. What options do I have and what would I have to do to implement it myself?

I'm using DevExpress XtraUserControl.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Register to the `Activated` event of the main form.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Activated +=new EventHandler(Form1_GotFocus);
}

public void Form1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your payload here
}
```

Note that if you close a dialog and return to the form, the event is fired again.

Comment: The Control contains a grid and I don't call any display method. I dropped the control onto a Form and when the Form is displayed the control is also displayed.

Comment: "when the Form is displayed..." So where does that happen? There needs to be some code where it is invoked.

Comment: I don't know. I minimize, restore and the form is displayed. Can you please explain? Doesn't WinForm handle all that itself?

Comment: "itself" does not mean that you cannot change that behavior. But I really don't understand what you do and what is happening or not happening...

Comment: `Application.Run(new MainForm());` Now I don't have to do anything else to display it. I don't have to do any `.Show()`.

Comment: Then place the payload in the constructor of MainForm as this gets called when you use the `new` keyword.

Comment: But then it would be only one time. I want it to run every time it is displayed.

Comment: Now problem is that the control is on a Tab Control, on one tab there are other controls and another, this Control, so this wouldn't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15931/discussion-between-trum-and-jan)